# Is it possible to register a custom webdriver in a Selenium grid?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I created a custom webdriver (for a custom browser) by extending RemoteWebDriver. I can easily use it as standalone, by simply instantiating the driver.

But actually I want to use it in a Selenium Grid. Is there a way to register this custom web driver on a node, so that I can use it with via RemoteWebDriver and desired capabilities? I so, what do I need to do.

Any hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below set of instructions to setup support for a custom browser type when running selenium tests against a Selenium Grid.

1. Implement the interface `org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverProvider` (or) extend `org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider` wherein you take care of building support for your custom browser.
2. Create a directory named `META-INF\services` under your main resources folder and ensure that this directory gets bundled into the jar, when you create a jar out of your project.
3. Create a service loader file named `org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverProvider` wherein you add the fully qualified class name of the new class you created in step (1) and place it in the directory created in step (2)
4. Bundle your project into a jar.
5. Now start the selenium node by adding the jar created in (4).

Now your new browser is ready to be supported by the Selenium Grid.

Please refer to [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/QtXKLSTotM0/-cIHfjVnAgAJ) selenium-users google forums thread which also talks about the same query wherein the user confirmed that the above mentioned approach worked for them.

You still need to take care of creating a new custom capabilities object from your client side when you instantiate the `RemoteWebDriver` object for your custom browser.

Answer (score 1):

The **WebDriver** (server) variants are specifically designed/created/modified continously to be able to drive the ever evolving *Web Browsers*.

So if you want to drive a **Custom Browser** through a **Custom Webdriver**, it seems to be the perfect approach.

At this point, it is not clear from the question if your *usecase* resembles as a case **where you don't actually want a browser**.

However, as per the configuration in [Browser.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/testing/drivers/Browser.java) the following set of *Browsers* are extensively tested before any release:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.testing.drivers;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public enum Browser {

  chrome,
  edge,
  ff,
  htmlunit,
  ie,
  none, // For those cases where you don't actually want a browser
  opera,
  operablink,
  safari;

  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Browser.class.getName());

  public static Browser detect() {
    String browserName = System.getProperty("selenium.browser");
    if (browserName == null) {
      log.info("No browser detected, returning null");
      return null;
    }

    try {
      return Browser.valueOf(browserName);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      log.severe("Cannot locate matching browser for: " + browserName);
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

### Solution

To make a provision for your own **Custom Webdriver** and **Custom Browser** you may need to add the relevant entries within **`Browser.java`** and other required files and you will be good to go.

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually I have both use cases, some of them with a custom browser and some that don't want a browser. If I understand you correct, then there is no chance to extend selenium without changing the sources, isn't it? To get the result I want, I have to fork Selenium and change the files containing browser specific parts by adding my custom browser. Right? Apart from that, I'm a bit confused, if I'm not wrong, then the Browser.java file you linked is a test source used to test Selenium itself. How does changing this help me with my tests for my application?

Comment: Well, **`Browser.java`** is supposed be your starting point. If you want a canonical answer on what exactly to change you need to share the **Custom Webdriver** and **Custom Browser** _source code_ which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Of course, that's beyond the scope. I just wanted to be sure, that I understood everything. Thanks for your help.